# is there a logical mistake at my function?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a function which compares 2 different 4 digit numbers.

If these numbers have some numbers at the same place it will be `+`, same numbers but at different place `-`.

For example, if one of the number is 5606 and the other is 6668 it should produce `+-`. However produces gives `+--` instead.

I changed numbers the to x and y to prevent one number to avoid re-use, but it still doesn't work.  Is there a mistake in my code?

```
public String comparenumbers(String number) {
    result ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (number.charAt(i) == fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)){
            result += "+";
            char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
            myNameChars[i] = 'x';
            fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
            char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
            myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
            number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (number.charAt(i) != fakecomputernumber.charAt(i) && 
          fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1){
            result += "-";
            char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
            myNameChars[i] = 'x';
            fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
            char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
            myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
            number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        }
    }
    if (result =="") {
        result += "miss";
    } else if (result =="++++") {
        result = "Congratz you won!!!";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `if(result =="")` this doesnt work. Use `equals()`

Comment: Why do you want it to turn into a x and - if you are not going to display it for each number. Why not just compare if the 4 digits equal the 4 digits you are looking for?

Comment: well, it works at my function, i tried and saw it is giving "miss" message, the problem is, it generates extra (-) signs sometimes.

Comment: CodeCamper, what i am trying to do is a game like battleship, it will give clues with "+" and "-" signs. I am changing numbers to x and y to prevent them to be used again. I want 1 number to be checked once, for example; if "number" in my function is 1011 and the hidden number is 3167, i want it to give only 1 "-" not 3

Comment: @TimCastelijns No, use `isEmpty()` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the second loop :

When you find out that `number.charAt(i)` appears somewhere in `fakecomputernumber`, you change the i'th character of `number` to 'y', which is fine. But you also change the i'th character of `fakecomputernumber` to 'x', which is wrong, since the i'th character of `fakecomputernumber` is not equal to the i'th character of `number`.

If fakecomputernumber is 5606 and number is 6668 :

After the first loop you have a single + and the Strings become : 6y68 and 5x06.

The sencond loop finds twice that 6 is contained in `fakecomputernumber`:

The first time it changes the Strings to yy68 and xx06.
The second time it changes the Strings to yyy8 and xxx6.

Therefore you get `+--` instead of `+-`.

What you should do is :

```
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(number.charAt(i)!=fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)&&fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1){
            result += "-";
            char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();    
            myNameChars[fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))] = 'x';            
            fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
            char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
            myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
            number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is running as written:

"+" sign due to position 2, both chars are 6

"-" signs due to:

```
if(number.charAt(i)!=fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)&&fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1)
```

> 5   6     true && true  --> "-" added to string
>
> 6   6     false && false
>
> 0   6     true  && false
>
> 6   8     true &&  true(6 do exist in 2nd string)   --> "-" added to string

I am not sure about problem statement so won't be able to fix your code until you share the same

**A logical error in code:**

Strings are immutable objects.

If we have two strings foo and bar:

foo==bar will be comparing the memory reference of these two objects.

foo.equals(bar) will compare the value stored inside the memory reference.

So, if you want to check what is in result String, you should use .equals(..) method and there is your logical error too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second loop if

```
 if(number.charAt(i)!=fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)&&fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1)`
```

ie the second condition  `fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1` check if the ith characrter of `number` is present in any index of `fakecomputernumber`  apart from ith character as you already checked it in first condition So
initially if

```
String fakecomputernumber="5606";
String number="6668";
//after first loop
result="+" //expected
number="6y68"  //expexted
fakecomputernumber="5x06" //expected

//in the second loop if for the zero index

 myNameChars[i] = 'x';  //wrong because i is not the index of fakecomputernumber character which is same to i index character of number 
 fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
```

So for the first iteration of second loop you know you have to change first element of `number` to `y` but you dont know the element of `fakecomputernumber` to be changed to `x`.So to solve the problem simply change the line

```
myNameChars[i] = 'x';
```

to

```
myNameChars[fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))] = 'x';
```

Complete code

```
String fakecomputernumber="5606";String number="6668";
 String result ="";
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(number.charAt(i)==fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)){
        result += "+";
        char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
        myNameChars[i] = 'x';
        fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
        char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
        myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
        number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
    }
}
System.out.println(result+number+fakecomputernumber);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(number.charAt(i)!=fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)&&((fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1))){
        result += "-"; System.out.println("inside "+i);
        char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
        myNameChars[fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))] = 'x';//change this line only
        fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
        char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
        myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
        number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        System.out.println(result+number+fakecomputernumber);
    }
}
if(result ==""){
    result += "miss";
}else if(result =="++++"){
    result = "Congratz you won!!!";
}
System.out.println(result);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vuR1OH)